# Laravel route long slug with id in URL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make my website (Laravel 5.4) have URL like this

```
http://example.com/im-a-stackoverflow-member-102345689.html
                             ^                  ^
                  {--------SLUG-----------}-{post_id}
```

I create a route like this.

```
/* Routing for accessing news detail */
Route::get('/{slug}-{article_id}.htm', 'articleController@getArticleDetailById')
    ->name('getArticleDetailById')
    ->where(['slug' => '[A-Za-z]+'])
    ->where(['article_id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

But is not work as my expectation URL, above code only work when I access link like this `http://example.com/im-102345689.html`. I can't use route rule as `/` for example `{slug}/{id}` because I need to keep all my old links alive.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks for help

Comment: use htaccess to redirect your routes to the laravel routes

Comment: Thanks for reply, but use htaccees to redirect is my last choice if use Larvel route is impossible

Comment: what problem exactly do you have with your current implementation?

Comment: `http://example.com/im-a-stackoverflow-member-102345689.html` <- I can't access link like this.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: right now i think that laravel sees the slug as [im] and the id as [a-stackoverflow-member-102345689]

Comment: Your route contains `htm` trailer, but the link - `html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your route regex to:

`->where(['slug' => '[A-Za-z-]+'])`

or

```
 ->where(['slug' => '[A-Za-z-0-9]+[^-0-9.]+'])
```

Comment: Why didn't you escape `-`?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan what do you mean by escape?

Comment: @madalinivascu can you explain this regex ?